# Trying to pause and resume a timer with same button

Tags: javascript, timer, playback, pause

I am having a little trouble with this code. I am currently have a button that when clicked starts a timer. It then also changes the icon of the button from a start icon to a stop icon. I would like to stop this timer when the button is clicked again and have it switch back the icon from start to stop. I have been stuck for awhile and tried many things but cant get it to work and would appreciate any help. I am sure its a simple issue I am just new to javascript. Thanks.

```
(function () {
"use strict";
  var minutesLabel = document.getElementById('t1-min'),
    secondsLabel = document.getElementById('t1-sec'),
    resetButton = document.getElementById('t1-reset'),
    startButton = document.getElementById('t1-play'),
    timer = null;


function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
    var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
    var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
    var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
    return {
        'total': t,
        'minutes': minutes,
        'seconds': seconds
    };

}

function initializeClock(endtime) {
        var timeinterval = setInterval(function () {
            var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);
            if (t.total <= 0) {
                clearInterval(timeinterval);
            }
            minutesLabel.innerHTML = t.minutes;
            secondsLabel.innerHTML = pad(t.seconds);
        }, 1000);
}

startButton.onclick = function runClock() {
    var timeInMinutes = minutesLabel.innerHTML,
        currentTime = Date.parse(new Date()),
        deadline = new Date(currentTime + timeInMinutes * 60 * 1000);
    initializeClock(deadline);
    startButton.innerHTML = ('<i class="far fa-stop-circle fa-2x float-right">');
}

function pad(val) {
    var valString = val + "";
    if (valString.length < 2) {
        return "0" + valString;
    } else {
        return valString;
    }
}
```

})();

Comment: I don't see any code for the stop button click. Also instead of switching the HTML of the startbutton, you could make two buttons one for start and one for stop and when the application starts have the stop button with display:none to hide it, then on the start button click, hide the start button and show the stop button and on stop button click do the opposite.

Comment: You need to keep track of the state of the timer. You should keep a variable around to determine whether the click is starting or stopping the timer and then handling each action appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make sure that the event listener in placed correctly on the `startButton` element by adding a function on `addEventLister` method like that:

```
startButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
   //code goes here
});
```

Then initialize the `timeinterval` variable in the **global scope** of the code so that it can be accessed from all functions, and add a `const` in which you can save the initial text of the `startButton`:

```
(function () {
  "use strict";
  const START_BUTTON_INITIAL_TEXT = "Start";  // initial constant text of the start button
  var minutesLabel = document.getElementById('t1-min'),
  secondsLabel = document.getElementById('t1-sec'),
  resetButton = document.getElementById('t1-reset'),
  startButton = document.getElementById('t1-play'),
  timer = null,
  timeinterval; // declared in the global scope
```

Then add an `id` equal to `t1-stop` for the `stopButton` icon element to make sure that it can be accurately accessed by the Javascript file from the DOM:

```
startButton.innerHTML = ('<i id="t1-stop" class="far fa-stop-circle fa-2x float-right">');
```

lastly add this if statement in `addEventListener` function of `startButton` to check whether a stop button exists in the DOM when the `startButton` is clicked:

```
startButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (document.getElementById("t1-stop") != null) { 
    clearInterval(timeinterval);
    var stopButton = document.getElementById("t1-stop");
    startButton.removeChild(stopButton);
    startButton.innerHTML = START_BUTTON_INITIAL_TEXT;
  }
```

The above code stops the `timeinterval` and removes the `stopButton` from the DOM then replaces the `innerHTML` of `startButton` with the initial text set as a constant at the top variable declaration.

---

All in all, your event listener function for the `startButton` should look something like that:

```
startButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (document.getElementById("t1-stop") != null) { 
        clearInterval(timeinterval);
        var stopButton = document.getElementById("t1-stop");
        startButton.removeChild(stopButton);
        startButton.innerHTML = START_BUTTON_INITIAL_TEXT;
        return; 
    }
    var timeInMinutes = minutesLabel.innerHTML,
        currentTime = Date.parse(new Date()),
        deadline = new Date(currentTime + timeInMinutes * 60 * 1000);
    initializeClock(deadline);
    startButton.innerHTML = ('<i id="t1-stop" class="far fa-stop-circle fa-2x float-right">');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response I will look into this as a solution